# Accessing MongoDB outside of connection callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know that similar questions have been asked, but no one actually shows code that does this, they only link to pages that also don't show code.

Anyway, basically my node server receives data on a socket.io event. I want that data to go into MongoDB. The problem is that all the code examples I've seen for mongo only manipulate the db inside the `MongoClient.connect` callback, using the `db` object.

Since, I will be getting a lot of this data, I don't want to initialize over and over again.

What I need is effectively this:

```
MongoClient.connect(("mongodb://" + process.env.IP + ":27017/feedback"),
function(err, db) { ... });
```

And then later:

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    db.doStuff();
});
```

Comment: Well you can always declare a global variable and assign the `db` (that you get in the success `connect` callback) to it. Using Global Variables isn't considered a good practice though.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Funny thing is, I tried that and the error said that the global I assigned was null.

Comment: I think your global may have been `null` because you provided a callback for `MongoClient.connect`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MongoClient.connect()` return a promise if you don't give it a callback, you can declare a global promise :

```
var connect = MongoClient.connect(url);

socket.on('data', function(data) {
  connect.then(function(db) {

  });
});

socket.on('otherData', function(data) {
  connect.then(function(db) {

  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid. Does it open a new connection every time onData is called?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load the connection into a var and just use that instead of re-establishing the connection for every query.

I use a similar approach myself, locating the connection code into a its own module, something like so:

> **NOTE:** This code is off-the-cuff, untested, and I'm a little drunk.

**connect.js**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports = function(params) {

  var ip = params.ip || process.env.IP;
  var port = params.port || 27017;
  var collection = params.collection;

  var db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://' + ip + ':' + port + '/' + collection);

  return db;

}
```

Then in any given other module in your app, you would require `connection.js` and pass the `params` for any given connection, like so:

**onFeedback.js**

```
var feedbackDB = require('./connection.js')({
  collection : 'feedback'
});

socket.on('data', function (data) {
  feedbackDB(function(db){
    db.doStuff();
  };
});
```

Comment: I would love to use your method here, but sadly I get an error saying that feedbackDB is not a function, and I don't know enough about module.exports to figure it out. I'm doing some reading now, but it'd be great if  you could help me out.